# Tensorflow Keras resizing layer causing a shape error with raw image

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, face-recognition, data-preprocessing

I'am new to ML and I'am just trying to build a face recognition CNN. After some time I was able to build my model, using data-augmentation and pre-processing layers to improve it accuracy. I've read on this [guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/preprocessing_layers?hl=en) that I could add those layers direct inside my model, so that when I export the model, i would'nt need to do all of the pre-processing/normalization thing.

My problem is, after I trained and exported the model, I tried to predict a raw image of me, but I just got a shape error, because the the raw image size is different from the expcted input_shape of the model, that I dont even had especified.

This is the model that I built

```
img_size = (196, 196)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  Resizing(img_size[0], img_size[1]),
  Rescaling(1.0 / 255),
  RandomZoom(0.2),
  RandomFlip('horizontal'),
  Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"),
  MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
  Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"),
  MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
  Flatten(),
  Dense(512, activation="relu"),
  Dropout(0.4),
  Dense(128, activation="relu"),
  Dropout(0.4),
  Dense(5, activation="softmax")
])
```

I've trained it with a dataset that I loaded using tf.image_dataset_from_directory

```
def load_dataset(subset):
  dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    database_dir,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset=subset,
    seed=321,
    shuffle=True,
    batch_size=64,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode='categorical')
  dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
  return dataset

train_dataset = load_dataset('training')
test_dataset = load_dataset('validation')


model.compile(
  optimizer='adam',
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
  train_dataset,
  validation_data=test_dataset,
  epochs=10)
```

Then I exported the model, using `model.save("model.h5")`

And finally, I tried to predict a new raw image of me.

```
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./model.h5")

image_file = tf.io.read_file("new_image.jpg")
image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(image_file)
image = tf.keras.utils.img_to_array(image)
image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
prediction = model.predict(image)
```

And got the following error, that dont even make sense to me, because I specifed in the Resizing layer a shape of (196, 196), but the error says that it was expecting a shape of (256, 256)

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_14" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256, 256, 3), found shape=(None, 223, 223, 3)
```

Well, this is where I'm stuck, any help will be welcome. Btw, sorry for any english misstakes, I'm using Google Translate. Also, this is my first post on StackOverflow, so if I missed something just tell me.

Comment: It seems you loaded the wrong model. Please check it again.

Comment: Hi, I don't think I can load/save the wrong model when using the "official" save/load functions of tensorflow, but I tried to load it again, even tried with  another model, but still got the shape error.

Comment: Your error is to weird. You created a model with a Resizing layer to make all inputs to be 196x196, and then you trained that model to get a model with input shape of 256x256x3? Please provide the full code (without sensitive information) for deeper investigation.

Comment: Hi @RafaelFogaçaHeringer, I tried to replicate your issue, it is working fine with the Flower Classification Dataset. Please find the gist [here](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/synandi/22e7ff0a701641aa0e9738d25469663b/74382926.ipynb). Thank you!